# Required columns and hidden columns

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find some Javascript to allow the following;

I would like to make a number of columns required, however these columns will be 'hide/show' based on the previous answer. That bit i have working fine.

The problem is; this only works when I leave all columns as optional, but I would like to make them all required. 
When they are hidden I would like them to change to optional. Is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried  using the Validation settings option? , below is an example maybe it can help in your case.

in this example i have three fields, `Name` (text) , `US Citizen` (Choice) and `US Address` (text).

in case  `US Citizen = Yes`, `US Address` field should be mandatory.

Navigate to **list settings** then **Validation settings** 
in the Formula section in my case i use the below formula:

```
=IF([US Citizen]="Yes",IF([US Address]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Click **OK** and test ,  `US address` field will be required only when the `US Citizen = Yes`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had not tried this but I have now, and is so close to getting me to where i wanted. so thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help @KatieHibberd

Comment: I have set up this validation, in my Javasript I hide/show columns depending on the answer to the first question using the change function. When I save an item, and i get my validation error. It also makes all columns now available in the form. Do you know how to prevent this? Many thanks in advance. Katie

Comment: @KatieHibberd please update your question with the script you're using

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have solved this issue today. I combined ready and change functions in my JS, and it works perfectly now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't toggle the Required setting on a field on a per-session basis. If it's required, it's required for everyone.

What you want to do is leave the column as optional and enforce your validation on the client side.

Comment: Thank you Derek! such a shame because this would be useful for us. At the minute required fields are hidden and the form won't save, but if those questions in another form are shown we would like to force them to provide an answer :-)